# compare length of prolog lists

Tags: prolog

I have the following prolog program:

```
len([X],[Y],Count) :-
       length(X,K),
       length(Y,I),
       K < I,
       Count is 0
   ;   I < K,
       Count is 2
   ;   I = K,
       Count is 1.
```

When I enter :
**`len( [1,2], [5,2,4], X ).`**

I get:  `Singleton variable in branch: K and I`

I looked up what this means here: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=singleton  I tried doing  `_K & _I` but you can only do that once.

This program should take two lists and compare the length of each list to determine the output value.

Comment: I do not get what your program is supposed to do. `Count` seems to be a comparator, not the count of the list. Furthermore the pattern matching is wrong.

Comment: Everything after the `length/2` goals needs to be wrapped in a pair of round brackets. And then `[X]` should probably be `X` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem with your code is that the head of the clause has an error:

```
len([X],[Y],Count) :- ...
```

this means that the first and second list **only can be singletons** (lists with one element). So we need to rewrite this to:

```
len(X,Y,Count) :- ...
```

The second problem is that [**the `;` has higher priority than `,`**](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse40), as a result the Prolog interpreter will interpret this as:

```
len(X,Y,Count) :-
    (
        length(X,K),
        length(Y,I),
        K < I,
        Count is 0
    );
    (
        I < K,
        Count is 2
    );
    (
        I = K,
        Count is 1
    ).
```

So that means that in case the first condition fails, Prolog will backtrack, and now in that branch, it sees `I < K`, but for Prolog, those are new variables (since these are in a different branch). The Prolog interpreter will warn you that this is odd, especially in the case you write `I < K`, since it requires `I` and `K` to be grounded, so this will go wrong.

You need to rewrite your program to:

```
len(X,Y,Count) :-
    length(X,K),
    length(Y,I),
    (
        (
            K < I,
            Count is 0
        );
        (
            I < K,
            Count is 2
        );
        (
            I = K,
            Count is 1
        )
    ).
```

or less verbose:

```
len(X,Y,Count) :-
    length(X,K),
    length(Y,I),
    (
        K < I,
        Count is 0
    ;   I < K,
        Count is 2
    ;   I = K,
        Count is 1
    ).
```

But this is of course quite cumbersome. A more elegant solution is to write a `compare/3` predicate first:

```
cmp(X,Y,0) :-
    X < Y.
cmp(X,Y,2) :-
    X > Y.
cmp(X,X,1).
```

and then write:

```
cmp(X,Y,0) :-
    X < Y.
cmp(X,Y,2) :-
    X > Y.
cmp(X,X,1).

len(X,Y,Cmp) :-
    length(X,K),
    length(Y,I),
    cmp(K,I,Cmp).
```

Comment: Your rewrite is just as bad as the original program. Please use `listing/0` to see how a common indentation looks like

Comment: @false: it has been modified in the meanwhile.

Comment: You still put `;` at the end - and use lots of unnecessary round brackets all around

Comment: :Please use `listing/0` to see what the Prolog community has found out... putting `;` at the end of a line is extremely misleading

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks i thought lists had to be in [ ] and could you explain what the singleton variable in branch means? from the website I referenced I could not make sense of it

Comment: It is already mentioned in the answer. A `;` means that this is a "logical" or. So that means Prolog will backtrack. It sees these traces as independent ones. And so in the second trace, you only mention `I` once, so Prolog warns you that this does not make much sense.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  Thank you, now i get it!